# how to configure Apache + SVN webDAV directory listing

Tags: html, svn, mod-dav-svn

I have an subversion server running with Apache `mod_dav_svn` and it works nicely but the browsing ability via HTML is a bit spartan. Is there a way to customize it at all?

[image]

There's two things I'd like to do to make a huge difference:

1. separate the directories from the files so all the directories are at the top. Right now everything is in alphabetical order. (the picture above happens to have all the directories preceding files in alphabetical order, but trust me, that's not the normal case)
2. List the basic file statistics (file size, mod time, last updated version, etc)

Is it posssible to do either of these with `mod_dav_svn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WebSvn](http://www.websvn.info/) looks like it might help you. I tried trac and it is very slick but I found it to be complicated and seems overkill for what you're looking for, imo.

Answer (score 4):

In a vanilla Subversion install, the web interface is very spartan by design.  (Remember the HTTP interface is designed for SVN clients, not human beings.)

You can customize the display somewhat via the [SVNIndexXSLT directive](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).  (Here is [a good place to start](http://www.reposstyle.com/)).

If you want something richer (with logs and diff features), you will need to install a special front end.  [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/) and [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) are very popular.  There is also [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/), but this is a higher-level tool.

[A list of other repo browsing tools.](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#browsers)

Just FYI, we use WebSVN for our repo instance.  It took some effort to get it up and running, but once it is setup you can pretty much leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box - that is, without modifying the source code. You might be interested in tools like [ViewSVN](http://viewsvn.berlios.de/) or the more sophisticated [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/).